# Windows 7 explorer pinned and recent items gone sometimes (and reappearing)

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

Since a few days, I intermittendly lose the pinned and recent items in the explorer taskbar (right clicking it)

I only see 'windows explorer', 'unpin ....' and 'close window'
a few minitues later the items are back, and a few moment later they're gone again.

Sometimes it takes a few seconds for the pinned and recent items to appear,

Comment: After this issue getting worser and worser. (in the end it never showed the recent nor pinned items), I cleaned out my temp directory and I got the pinned items back for good (hopefully), but ofcourse the recent items are gone.

Comment: Also a thread happening in the [Microsoft forums](http://social.answers.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w7desktop/thread/a790f38f-d199-44b8-9a47-ac637e0905f6), but no resolution, there, either.